# What does "the world takes you at your own estimate" mean?

Tags: sentence

I was looking for some quotes of "think highly of" when this sentence showed up repeatedly among the top results.

"Think highly of yourself because the world takes you at your own estimate."

I think it means the world sees you the way you see yourself? But I'm not sure.

Comment: That’s it. . . .

Comment: What is it about the sentence that you’re unsure about? It seems a fairly straightforward metaphor to me.

Comment: The quoted sentence is actually (potentially) nonsensical. What if your estimate of yourself is that you don't do anything well? If that were the case, then the sentence would be contradicting itself. Your own restatement, on the other hand, actually has internal logic to it. It may be what the sentence *meant* to say, but not what it *literally* said. Or, in a different interpretation, maybe it means *The world thinks you're good at **estimating** your own worth. It greatly appreciates your **judgment**. Even if you judge yourself poorly, at least you're good at doing that.*